# How to add dynamic datetime to the file name in the <attachment> tag in Xml

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to add dynamic timestamp with the attachment file test.dat as (test_currentDateTime.dat)

sample code which I need to modify:

```
<node name="testEmail" type="emailoutput"
subject="this is a test mail with an attachment"
xsl="&XSLPATH;test.xsl" outputType="text/plain" >
<attachment type="text/plain" name="test.dat"/>  
</node>
```

How can this be done in the `attachment` tag that is inside the node tag in xml.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with [xml-schema]?